# Необходимо вытащить массив об]ектов из jsp

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc

Есть следующая проблема, не могу понять почему не инициализируются поля у массива объектов. Но по порядку. Есть три entity, contact, contactteldetail, и hobby.
contact, contactteldetail - связь многие ко многим, а хобби один ко многим.

```
public class Contact implements Serializable {
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date birthDate;
    private int version;
    private Set<ContactTelDetail> contactDetails = new HashSet<>();//коллекция entity
    private Set<Hobby> hobbies = new HashSet<>();//коллекция entity

public class ContactTelDetail implements Serializable{
    private int id;
    private int contactId;
    private String telType;
    private String telNumber;
    private int version;
    private Contact contact;
```

в контроллере создаю метод updateForm который направляет на jsp где идет обновление, и передает объект contact наполненный значениями(то есть contact, и hashset contactteldetail и hobbie). И метод update который собственно и обрабатывает все объекты.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "contacts/{id}", params = "form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String update(Contact contact, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                         RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Locale locale) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            model.addAttribute("message", new Message("error",
                    messageSource.getMessage("contact_save_fail", new Object[]{}, locale)));
            model.addAttribute("contact", contact);
            return "contacts/update";
        }
        model.asMap().clear();
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", new Message("success",
                messageSource.getMessage("contact_save_success", new Object[]{}, locale)));
        contactService.save(contact);
        return "redirect:/contacts/" + UrlUtil.encodeUrlPathSegment(contact.getId().toString(),
                httpServletRequest);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "contacts/{id}", params = "form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String updateForm(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model uiModel) {
        Contact list = contactService.findAllWithDetail()
                .stream().filter(a -> a.getId().equals(id))
                .findFirst().orElse(null);
        uiModel.addAttribute("contact", list);

        return "contacts/update";
    }
```

и есть следующая jsp форма куда все атрибуты из updateForm успешно передаются, но в метод update contactdetails инициализируются нулями, точнее я не могу передать их совсем никак обьекты, поля, аттрибуты, ничего не инициализируется, пробовал по разному используя только jstl, spring и html.

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<html>

<div>

    <spring:message code="label_contact_new" var="labelContactNew"/>
    <spring:message code="label_contact_update" var="labelContactUpdate"/>
    <spring:message code="label_contact_first_name" var="labelContactFirstName"/>
    <spring:message code="label_contact_last_name" var="labelContactLastName"/>
    <spring:message code="label_contact_birth_date" var="labelContactBirthDate"/>
    <spring:message code="label_contactteldetails_telnumber" var="labelTelNumber"/>
    <spring:message code="label_contactteldetails_teltype" var="labelTelType"/>
    <spring:message code="label_hobby" var="labelHobby"/>

    <spring:eval expression="contact.id == null ? labelContactNew:labelContactUpdate"
                 var="formTitle"/>

    <h1>${formTitle}</h1>

    <div id="contactUpdate">
        <form:form modelAttribute="contact" id="contactUpdateForm" method="post">

            <c:if test="${not empty message}">
                <div id="message" class="${message.type}">${message.message}</div>
            </c:if>

            <div class="section1">
                <h2>General Informaion</h2>

                <form:label path="firstName">
                    ${labelContactFirstName}*
                </form:label>
                <form:input path="firstName"/>
                <div>
                    <form:errors path="firstName" cssClass="error"/>
                </div>
                <p/>

                <form:label path="lastName">
                    ${labelContactLastName}*
                </form:label>
                <form:input path="lastName"/>
                <div>
                    <form:errors path="lastName" cssClass="error"/>
                </div>
                <p/>

                <form:label path="birthDate">
                    ${labelContactBirthDate}
                </form:label>
                <form:input path="birthDate" id="birthDate"/>
                <div>
                    <form:errors path="birthDate" cssClass="error"/>
                </div>
                <p/>

            </div>
***вот тут собственно и должно происходить изменение данных***
                    <table>
                        <c:forEach items="${contact.contactDetails}" var="detailsMap" varStatus="entry">
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="text" name="${detailsMap.telType}" value="${detailsMap.telNumber}"/></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="${detailsMap.telNumber}" value="${detailsMap.telType}"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only">
                        <span class="ui-button-text">Save</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="reset" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only">
                        <span class="ui-button-text">Reset</span>
                    </button>
                </form:form>
            </div>

            <form:hidden path="version"/>

</html>
```

В дебаге четко видно contactteldetails имеет все поля null. Повторюсь мне надо изменить лишь пару полей в тех коллекциях hashsaet в contact, которые являются entity. но к сожалению я не знаю как это реализовать( помогите пожалуйста в этом вопросе, и в понимании почему же когда передаю в update contactteldetails инициализируются null.